# opencv K-Means understanding centers matrix

Tags: opencv, k-means

Documentation describes output centers as:
centers – Output matrix of the cluster centers, one row per each cluster center.
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html
I have an issue, when i set k=2 i have output matrix as follow:

[[ 39  46  56]
 [205 208 207]]

I don't understand what columns means ? 
Which value in first row is real center of cluster ?

Comment: How many features does your data contain? Is it color images?

Comment: yes, this is simple example like this: 
https://morioh.com/p/b6763f7527d5

Comment: I think i get it.
column number is the feature number ?

Comment: Yep. I think you have it. If it is one channel data, then you would have two centers each one only a single feature

Comment: Thanks a lot for you solution